# Can UK residents from eligible countries use the ePassport gates in the UK?

Tags: uk, us-citizens, uk-residents, customs-and-immigration

Now [US citizens and more can use ePassport gates](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/epassport-gates-eligibility-expansion-confirmed-for-june) when coming to the UK, can UK residents that are US citizens use these gates?

I notice that if you are a US citizen, coming to study for 6 months or less, you need to see an officer to get a stamp to study.

Was wondering if a resident needs to see an officer too, so they're not just admitted for 6 months at the ePassport gate like a tourist would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can use the ePassport gates if you're a UK resident and from a country that is allowed to use the ePassport gates.

https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control

> **If you’re from a non-EEA country**
>
> You no longer have to fill in a
>   landing card. Your passport (and visa if you have one) will be checked
>   at border control. You’ll usually be asked why you’re coming to the
>   UK.
>
> You may be able to use the automatic ePassport gates if you’re from:
>
> - Australia
> - Canada
> - Japan
> - New Zealand
> - Singapore
> - South Korea
> - United States
>
> You must also:
>
> - be aged 12 or over (if you’re between 12 and 17, you must be
>     accompanied by an adult)
> - **have a valid visa or a biometric residence permit**
> - have a valid passport for the duration of your stay have a
> - passport with a ‘chip’ on it

Comment: I suspect you would still see an officer after the gates to get a stamp?

Comment: @kiradotee No, as explained further down in the link provided in the answer, if you need (or want) a stamp because of the type of visa you hold, you can’t use the ePassport gates because you can’t get a stamp afterwards.

Comment: @Traveller so I guess it's simply assumed people would know that if the gates open for them then they can stay up to 6 months?

Comment: @kiradotee after you go through the gate there is a sign telling them they have 6 months leave to enter, cant work or claim benefits etc. My question was for residents if they could use it too. Heres more info for tourists from these nations https://www.gov.uk/government/news/epassport-gates-eligibility-expansion-confirmed-for-june